# Проблема с checkbox

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени. Недавно начал изучение js. Столкнулся с проблемой чекбокса. не получается получить нужный результат.

Таким образом выглядят пункты калькулятора, это пользовательский ввод кол-ва единиц:

```html
<div class="row" data-price="100">
  <div class="icon door"></div>
  <div class="left" data-edit="" contenteditable="true">
    <span class="z">Наименование</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span data-edit="" contenteditable="true">кол-во</span>
    <div class="counter"><span class="minus">—</span><span class="count null">0</span><span class="plus">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Так скрипт:

```js
var base = parseInt($('#calculator .wrapper').attr('data-base'));
var settings = [];
function RemoveAmount(headline) {
    for(var i=0; i<settings.length; i++) {
        if(settings[i][0]==headline) {
            settings[i][1]--;
        }
        if(settings[i][1]==0) {
            settings.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
function AddAmount(headline, amount, price) {
    var price_int = parseInt(price);
    var newItem = [headline, amount, price_int];
    if(settings.length==0) {
        settings.push(newItem);
    } else {
        var flag = false;
        var flag_i = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<settings.length; i++) {
            if(settings[i][0]==headline) {
                flag_i = i;
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            settings[flag_i][1]++;
        } else {
            settings.push(newItem);
        }
    }
}
function TotalSum(settings_array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<settings_array.length; i++) {
        sum += settings_array[i][1]*settings_array[i][2];
    }
    return sum;
}
/*
$('#calculator .wrapper .row').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(this).find('.right').append('<div class="counter"><span class="minus">−</span><span class="count null">0</span><span class="plus">+</span></div>');
});
*/
$("#calculator .minus").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_value = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.count').text())-1;
    var headline = $(this).parents('.row').find('.left .z').text();
    if(new_value<0) {
        alert('Количество не может быть отрицательной величиной.');
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.count').text(new_value);
        RemoveAmount(headline);
        if(settings.length==0) {
            var result = 0;
        } else {
            var result = TotalSum(settings)+base;
        }
        result = number_format(result, 0, '.', ' ');
        $('#CalculatorResult, #CalculatorResultModal').text(result);
    }
    if(new_value==0) {
        $(this).parent().find('.count').addClass('null');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.count').removeClass('null');
    }
});
$("#calculator .plus").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_value = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.count').text())+1;
    $(this).parent().find('.count').text(new_value);
    $(this).parent().find('.count').removeClass('null');
    var headline = $(this).parents('.row').find('.left .z').text();
    var price = $(this).parents('.row').attr('data-price');
    AddAmount(headline, new_value, price);
    var result = TotalSum(settings)+base;
    result = number_format(result, 0, '.', ' ');
    $('#CalculatorResult, #CalculatorResultModal').text(result);
});
function ToFormData(data) {
    var str = '';       
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        str = str+data[i].join(",");
        if(i!=(data.length-1)) {
            str = str+'=';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Таким образом на странице делаю чекбокс:

```html
<div class="row" data-price="1000">
  <div class="icon heating"></div>
  <div class="left" data-edit="" contenteditable="true">
    <span class="z">Чекбокс</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span data-edit="" contenteditable="true">Значение</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">
    <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Совершенно не ясно что прописать в скрипте, чтобы он плюсовал сумму "1000" к общей сумме...

Comment: вам бы сократить код, акцентируя только нерабочий момент. а то пересматривать всё полотно не каждый согласится

Comment: Знал бы где искать, сократил. по этому предоставил все что есть... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно сделать изменение в **html**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" value="1000">
<label for="checkbox-1">Плюс 1000</label>
```

Далее нам нужно "повесить" на элемент **input[type=checkbox]** событие **onchange** с нужной нам обработкой:

```
$('#checkbox-1').on('change', function () {
    var result;

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        result = parseInt(this.value);
    }

    result += TotalSum(settings);
    result = number_format(result, 0, '.', ' ');
    $('#CalculatorResult, #CalculatorResultModal').text(result);
});
```

---

#### Для множества checkbox:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var result = 0;

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        result += parseInt(this.value);
    });

    result += TotalSum(settings);
    result = number_format(result, 0, '.', ' ');
    $('#CalculatorResult, #CalculatorResultModal').text(result);
});
```

Comment: Ух ты! Огромное спасибо! Жаль репутацию ставить не могу. Помогли.
Но у меня есть такая функция:
<div class="wrapper" data-base="100">
Она добавляет сумму к итогу.
В скрипте самая верхняя строчка:
var base = parseInt($('#calculator .wrapper').attr('data-base'));

Comment: И теперь еще столкнулся с проблемой.
checkbox-1 - это один из чекбоксов. Есть еще checkbox-2 и т.д.
Пишу в скрипте копии с заменой $('#checkbox-1') в итоге получаю не суммирование а замену одной суммы другой :(

Comment: Решил вопрос с data-base так:
result += TotalSum(settings)+base;

Остается вопрос остальных чекбоксов и обнулении итоговой суммы при снятии чекбокса.

Comment: Roman, Ваша проблема с checkbox-ами сугубо из-за такой плохой структуры кода. Даже мне тяжело понять что к чему. Сейчас дополню свой ответ и перепишу под множество чекбоксов

Comment: Учусь еще :)
Буду признателен. третий день ковыряюсь...

Comment: ДАЙ ВАМ БОГ ЗДОРОВЬЯ! Спасибо.